Is it possible to configure datadog to include stack trace in content or default search
I would like to see and search logs with stacktraces, unfortunately DataDog seems to put stack traces into separate stack_trace field and does not search for it by default, unless I explicitly search by attribute (stack_trace:*foo*).
Is it possible to configure DataDog such that searches by default include stack_trace, i.e. instead of stack_trace:*foo* I can just search for foo.
Also is it possible to configure the log view such that stack trace is displayed below content as opposed to separate column?
